# ERROR: more than one row returned by subquery

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, subquery

I have the following SQL query (Using Postgre, pgAdmin3)

```
update "Customers"
set "PID"=(select PID
from person
left join "Customers"
on "Customers"."Email"=person.Email
where "Customers"."Email"!='' and "Customers"."Email" is not null)
```

The subquery runs just fine and returns the list of Customer emails matched to the PID it found in the person table.

I need to use this list of PIDs to update the PID field in the Customer table.

Any advice?

Comment: What data type is column PID of table Customers? Your query doesn't make sense. Because you are writing a list of results into a single cell.

Comment: You want to update the customers PIDs with the customers PIDs? That doesn't seem to make much sense. And why do you outer join customers when you later dismiss outer-joined records with `and "Customers"."Email" is not null`? This doesn't seem to make sense either. Then when you update, you fill each record's PID with what the subquery gives you. You say the subquery gets you a list of PIDs. So you are trying to fill each PID with the list of PIDs? Probably not. So what is it you really want to achieve?

Comment: You want a *scalar subquery* : a subquery that yields **exactly one value**. Yours doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

It's not completely clear from your query, but I think you're looking for something like this:

```
update "Customers" as c
set "PID"=p.PID
from person AS p
where c."Email"=p.Email
and c."Email"!='' and c."Email" is not null
```